# npx pod-install error. Aborting run and An unexpected error was encountered

Tags: macos, react-native, npm, expo, create-react-native-app

When I successfully installed create-react-native-app without getting an error, This warning showed up and when I type that, the terminal gave me an error or warning like that: `An unexpected error was encountered. Please report it as a bug:`

Is there anyone who got code this error code or like that? Please help me to be able to solve this problem.

```
⚠️  Before running your app on iOS, make sure you have CocoaPods installed and initialize the project:

  cd travel-app-react-native/ios
  npx pod-install

oguzhanatalay@Oguzhans-Mac Desktop % cd travel-app-react-native 
oguzhanatalay@Oguzhans-Mac travel-app-react-native % npx pod-install
npx: installed 1 in 6.118s
Scanning for pods...
1.10.0
> pod install
Installing unimodules:
 expo-constants@9.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-constants/ios
 expo-error-recovery@1.3.0 from ../node_modules/expo-error-recovery/ios
 expo-file-system@9.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios
 expo-font@8.3.0 from ../node_modules/expo-font/ios
 expo-image-loader@1.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-image-loader/ios
 expo-keep-awake@8.3.0 from ../node_modules/expo-keep-awake/ios
 expo-linear-gradient@8.3.1 from ../node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/ios
 expo-location@9.0.1 from ../node_modules/expo-location/ios
 expo-permissions@9.3.0 from ../node_modules/expo-permissions/ios
 expo-splash-screen@0.6.2 from ../node_modules/expo-splash-screen/ios
 expo-sqlite@8.4.0 from ../node_modules/expo-sqlite/ios
 expo-updates@0.3.5 from ../node_modules/expo-updates/ios
 unimodules-app-loader@1.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-app-loader/ios
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@5.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface/ios
 unimodules-camera-interface@5.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-camera-interface/ios
 unimodules-constants-interface@5.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-constants-interface/ios
 unimodules-core@5.5.1 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@5.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-face-detector-interface/ios
 unimodules-file-system-interface@5.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-file-system-interface/ios
 unimodules-font-interface@5.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-font-interface/ios
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@5.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-image-loader-interface/ios
 unimodules-permissions-interface@5.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface/ios
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@5.6.0 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios
 unimodules-sensors-interface@5.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-sensors-interface/ios
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@5.3.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios

Auto-linking React Native modules for target `travelappreactnative`: RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, and RNScreens
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.4)
Installing CocoaLibEvent (1.0.0)
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing EXConstants (9.2.0)
Installing EXErrorRecovery (1.3.0)
Installing EXFileSystem (9.2.0)
Installing EXFont (8.3.0)
Installing EXImageLoader (1.2.0)
Installing EXKeepAwake (8.3.0)
Installing EXLinearGradient (8.3.1)
Installing EXLocation (9.0.1)
Installing EXPermissions (9.3.0)
Installing EXSQLite (8.4.0)
Installing EXSplashScreen (0.6.2)
Installing EXUpdates (0.3.5)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.63.3)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.63.3)
Installing Flipper (0.54.0)
Installing Flipper-DoubleConversion (1.1.7)
Installing Flipper-Folly (2.3.0)
Installing Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h
/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif
/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif
/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
/Users/oguzhanatalay/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/oguzhanatalay/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/oguzhanatalay/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


Aborting run
An unexpected error was encountered. Please report it as a bug:
Error
    at CocoaPodsPackageManager._installAsync (/Users/oguzhanatalay/.npm/_npx/4500/lib/node_modules/pod-install/build/index.js:2:85721)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: u should do npx pod-install in your parent directory, not within ios directory. can u try if it solves your problem?

Comment: he did not `cd` into the `ios` directory. i believe he ran the command on the top level of his project directory.

Comment: Yes, I already ran in my parent directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the error lies with this error statement:

```
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
```

Taken from a [github thread for an old issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18408#issuecomment-386696744), try these steps:

run this command:
`xcrun -k --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path`

if the output is:

```
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
```

then run this: `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

Then install pod again.